# FileNotFoundException but File Exists and permissions are set to all access

Tags: java

I've seen this question several times, but not with a solution that seems to address my case.

Here's the code:

```
try {
    File f = new File("C:\\config\\test.properties");
    System.out.println("Path: [" + f.getAbsolutePath() + "]");
    System.out.println("Can.Path: [" + f.getCanonicalPath() + "]");
    System.out.println("Exists? " + f.exists());
    System.out.println("CanRead? " + f.canRead());
    System.out.println("Dir? " + f.isDirectory());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Path: [C:\config\test.properties]
Can.Path: [C:\config\test.properties]
Exists? false
CanRead? false
Dir? false
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\config\test.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.gallup.gtm.core.server.database.DatabaseConnection.main(DatabaseConnection.java:40)
```

But if we copy/paste the file path into Windows Run command, the file opens so it's there and the path is correct. Things we've tried:

- Move file to system root ("C:")
- Rename File
- Call trim() on the path.
- Set file permissions on the file to "Full Control" for "Everyone"

Is there anything we've missed? Is there another way we can troubleshoot this to figure out what's going on?

This is running on a Jr. Developer's new computer. Others are able to run this code without any trouble, so I suspect an issue there. But I'm out of ideas were to look. This is on Java 8 running on Windows 7.

Comment: Permissions of the application user?

Comment: Consider looking into permissions on C:\ and on C:\config.  Of course you don't want to grant `Everyone` full control of these, especially the former, but perhaps the problem is there.

Comment: One potential cause might be that Java is being sandboxed by some anti-virus software.

Comment: The file might be `symlinked`

Comment: What is the output of `new File("C:\\config").list()`?